# Added textbox using JSF tags but NOT visible on the screen

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, glassfish, facelets

I have a Facelet file with JSF tags to display a label, an input field and a button, but those parts are are not visible in the browser when I run it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
     <h:head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
         <title> supply a title</title>
     </h:head>
     <h:body>
         <h:form>
              Name:
            <h:outputLabel value="First Name:"> </h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{DataForm.name}"></h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton value="Doctor Register" action="#{DataForm.submit}">       </h:commandButton>


         </h:form>
     </h:body>
 </html>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it? I am using netbeans 6.9.1 Glassfish 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen when the `FacesServlet` is not been invoked. It's the one responsible for parsing the Facelet file and doing all the JSF works.

You need to ensure that your request URL (the one which you see in the browser address bar) matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as it is been mapped in the `web.xml`. If it's for example mapped on an URL pattern of `*.jsf`, then you need to ensure that you open the page in browser by

> http://localhost:8080/contextname/index.jsf

Or when you want to invoke the `FacesServlet` on every `*.xhtml` request, then you need to change the URL pattern of the mapping in `web.xml` accordingly (recommended)

```xml
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

Comment: that's very helpful, by default the pattern is /faces/*

Comment: @Bor: that was the JSF 1.0 default. Some IDEs don't catch up that. In Eclipse you can change it once and it'll remember that for future projects.